# How to use a variable inside a carbon datetime?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Good morning guys, i need to have a custom date that always has the current date but a certain time to be able to compare two dates and get the remaining time. At the moment something like this occurred to me:

```
 $day=date("d");
            $dayy= now();
            $datelim= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-05-',$day, '22:00:02');
return view('fen.index', [

        'works' => Period::select('paperiod.descriptionp','pamatrixinfoperio.description', 'pamatrixinfoperio.codpar')
                ->join('pamatrixinfoperio', 'pamatrixinfoperio.cod_paperiod', '=', 'paperiod.cod')
                ->where('pamatrixinfoperio.read_at', '=', 0, 'AND')
                ->where('pamatrixinfoperio.cod_paperiod', '=', 1)
                ->get(),
        'Periodres' => $fechalim

        ]);
```

but I don't know how to concatenate that variable day in the carbon `'2020-05-',$day, '22:00:02'` , How could I use it because my objective is that the variable always has the current day, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, but that the time is always the same.

On the other hand, I don't know if they could help me. How can I compare dayy and datelim? So in the view I can have for example: "The work is about to end in 3 days, 3 hours and 20 seconds" I hope you can help me, because I find more complex examples in carbon but not basic and I don't know how to do this :(

my view is this:

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">WorksF</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        Welcome {{Auth::user()->name}}, Lasis informs you that the following files are about to end in:
@foreach($works as $work)
            <li class="list-group-item">
            {{$work->description}} 
            you have the next time to deliver the report:
            <b>{{$Periodres}}</b>
   </li>
@endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

As you can see the view is not finished but I am looking for something similar, Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation in PHP use `.` not `,` and you need a space between `$day` and the hour.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-05-' . $day . ' 22:00:02');
```

Of course `Carbon::create()` as suggested by Nacho is appropriate, but still `Carbon::createFromFormat()` works also fine if the given input is given as 1 single string and matches the format.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case you can use:
Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)